# WordPress. Used remove_cap(), getting "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." even after removing this function

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress v5.5.1, I have used below function to restrict authors to publish the posts:

```
function set_capabilities() {
    $author = get_role('author');
    $caps = array(
        'edit_others_posts',
        'edit_others_pages',
        'publish_posts',
        'delete_posts',
        'delete_published_posts',
    );

    foreach ($caps as $cap) {
        $author->remove_cap($cap);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'set_capabilities');
```

It resulted in complete removal of posts page and adding new posts at `wp-admin/post-new.php`.

I have removed the `set_capabilities()` function, still getting the error "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.".

I have tried resetting the `wp-capabilities`, still it did not worked for me.

I have tried adding a new user with `author` role, the new user have the same issue as well.

How can I have the authors create a post accessing `wp-admin/post-new.php` again?

Comment: This issue is on localhost on wampserver only; however on production this error is not there.

Comment: how did you try to reset the `wp-capabilities` ?

Comment: Within `phpmyadmin`

Comment: Can you specify which table you modified, which record and what value did you update with?

Comment: Modified `wp_usermeta->wp_capabilities` field with `a:1:{s:6:"author";b:1;}` to restore the original capabilities.

Comment: the ` wp_usermeta->wp_capabilities` table will store the capabilities of one user identified by the ` wp_usermeta->user_id`. All capabilities would be stored in your `wp_options` where `option_name`= 'wp_user_roles' ` (assuming your db prefix is `wp` based on your previous response)  as well. Can you share that option value ?

Comment: This should be a long string. Also if you do not wish to share all these details you could extract the author details only. i.e if we stored the `wp_user_roles` string option value in a variable `$capabilities`  We are particularly interested in `<?php echo json_encode( unserialize($capabilities)['author']); ?> . You could also use <?php get_option('wp_user_roles') ?> in wordpress to get this value instead of from phpmyadmin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221929/discussion-between-theking-and-ggordon).

Comment: Thank you @ggordon for talking me to the real issue. I have replaced `wp_options->wp_user_roles` values with the values from my production site; and it is working now. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Please post that as your answer, so I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

After calling `$author->remove_cap($cap)` the capability was removed from the author role, not only in memory but also in the database (see reference section below for implementation and links). As a result, removing the call to `set_capabilities()` or adding a new user to the role would not reset the role capabilities.

### Solutions

#### Approach 1 - Using Wordpress

You could do the opposite of `set_capabilities()` eg `add_capabilities()` as shown below to re-assign these privileges both in memory and database using the official Wordpress API

```
function add_capabilities() {
    $author = get_role('author');
    $caps = array(
        'edit_others_posts',
        'edit_others_pages',
        'publish_posts',
        'delete_posts',
        'delete_published_posts',
    );

    foreach ($caps as $cap) {
        $author->add_cap($cap);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'add_capabilities');
```

From your `users` administration page you could then ensure the user is assigned the desired role of author.

#### Approach 2 - Manually accessing and updating your database

Assuming `wp_` as your database prefix, you could ensure that the user is indeed assigned the role of `author` and if not manually assign this. This is in your `wp_usermeta` table, you should see a record with the `user_id` in question and the name `wp_capabilities`. The value stores a php serialized array of roles for example if the user was just an author the value would be `a:1:{s:6:"author";b:1;}`.

Now that you have ensured the user is indeed in the role, all role capabilities are stored in `wp_options` table within option_name `wp_user_roles`. Again, this is a long serialized php associative array that is structed as such (assume `$roleName` to be any role eg. 'author')

```
["$roleName"=>[
     'name'=>"$roleName",
     'capabilities'=>[
         'edit_others_posts',
        'edit_others_pages',
        'publish_posts',
        'delete_posts',
        'delete_published_posts',
     ]
 ]
]
```

If you had a backup or another working location you could restore it. If you desire to manually modify these values, due to the need for php serialization, I would recommend writing custom code in php to achieve such as a last resort if using `Solution 1` is not helpful or the Wordpress methods are not available eg. working from a different client/server/location.

### Additional Resources and References

See implementation from official Wordpress Documenation

$author = [get_role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_role/)('author'); --> returns a [WP_Role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/) in `$author`

And an implementation of the `remove_cap` called and the `add_cap` I will make reference to  retrieved from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_roles/ is included below:

```
/**
     * Add capability to role.
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     *
     * @param string $role  Role name.
     * @param string $cap   Capability name.
     * @param bool   $grant Optional. Whether role is capable of performing capability.
     *                      Default true.
     */
    public function add_cap( $role, $cap, $grant = true ) {
        if ( ! isset( $this->roles[ $role ] ) ) {
            return;
        }
 
        $this->roles[ $role ]['capabilities'][ $cap ] = $grant;
        if ( $this->use_db ) {
            update_option( $this->role_key, $this->roles );
        }
    }
 
    /**
     * Remove capability from role.
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     *
     * @param string $role Role name.
     * @param string $cap  Capability name.
     */
    public function remove_cap( $role, $cap ) {
        if ( ! isset( $this->roles[ $role ] ) ) {
            return;
        }
 
        unset( $this->roles[ $role ]['capabilities'][ $cap ] );
        if ( $this->use_db ) {
            update_option( $this->role_key, $this->roles );
        }
    }
```